# label or instruction expected at start of line YASM

Tags: assembly, yasm

I'm trying to build assembly YASM code that is supposed to calculate the distance between two points (A and B) on 2D plane.

This the command that I'm using to build the code:

```
yasm -f elf64 -g dwarf2 -l distance.lst distance.asm
```

> distance.asm:2: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
>   distance.asm:4: error: label or instruction expected at start of line

I'm new to assembly and can' figure out how to fix error:

```
    segment .data
Ax  dq      0       ; x coordinate of A
Ay  dq      0       ; y coordinate of A
Bx  dq      1       ; x coordinate of B
By  dq      1       ; y coordinate of B

    segment .text
    global _start
_start:
mov     rax,    [Ax]    ; Writing values
mov     rbx,    [Ay]    ; of A and B
mov     rcx,    [Bx]    ; coordinates to
mov     rdx,    [By]    ; registers
sub     rax,    rcx     ; Length of the first cathetus
sub     rbx,    rdx     ; Length of the second cathetus
imul    rax,    rbx     ; Suqare of distanse between A and B
```

My question is: why am I getting error shown above?
(I have read similar questions on stackoverflow, but I still couldn't figure out what is wrong with my code)

Comment: `ax` and `bx` are register names, so cannot be used as labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of labels

```
Ax, Ay, Bx, By
```

use others, e. g.

```
Mx, My, Nx, Ny
```

because labels must not be register names as `AX`, `BX`, `CX`, ... (`Ay` and `By` are OK).